# Stable Diffusion XL becomes more abstract (less photorealistic) over time

Tags: stable-diffusion, generative-art

I'm using the Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion XL. Whatever settings I select, if I use it for a period of a couple of days (say, 30-50 images generated--I'm just playing with it right now), the images drift from photorealistic to absurdly abstract. There's also a weird thing where you prompt for one person, but get a set of near-identical twins. This one is the result of the prompt, "Nervous-looking man in swim trunks on a diving board, knees slightly bent and hands together."

[image: Weird abstract image of what should be one man diving but looks like two men peeing]

The abstraction seems unaffected by any WebUI settings. The only way I've found to get back to photorealistic imagery is to delete configuration files (config.json) ... but manually changing the settings doesn't work. Is this a bug? Is there some magic setting I'm missing?

That's Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion XL on Debian GNU/Linux. It doesn't recognize my Radeon GPU, so currently using CPU only. Flags are

```
 --skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half --opt-sdp-attention --opt-split-attention
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: This is an enormous topic with a lot of variance. It's particularly difficult to debug what a particular prompt "should" be generating with any given combination of settings.

But if you think there's a bug involving repeated generations you should try manually setting the seed to the first image you generated and retrying the original prompt. Assuming no bugs, the new image should be identical to the first one you created.

Comment: I don't consider this an answer, but I have a few suggestions. Your mileage may vary. 

1) My understanding is that SDXL isn't great with low resolutions. If that image was generated at 512x386, it may just be too small. 2) Repeated subjects happen sometimes. I don't know of a good way to avoid that, except trying different seeds. 3) It looks burned; your CFG scale may be too high. I rarely go above 7 for SDXL. 4) Negative prompts can also help. Try adding "photograph" or "photorealistic" to the prompt and "abstract" to the negative prompt. This helps tune it to the style you're going for.